# On member join event message doesn't work - discord.py

Tags: python, discord

**I'm very new to discord.py**, I want to learn python and make a simple bot for my server.
I want make a bot that sends a message when someone joins server. But the bot won't send any message. I tried so many solutions but none work.

No error in console. Just 'on_member_join' doesn't work; ping and console message methods work.

Here is my code:

```
    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands
    
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='*')
    TOKEN = '----my token here----'
    
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print('Bot is ready')
    
    @client.event
    async def on_member_join(member):
        channel = client.get_channel(764960656553934879)
        await channel.send('Hello')
    
    @client.command()
    async def ping(ctx):
        await ctx.send('Pong!')
    
    client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: **I found out that the on_member_join event does not run at all when a member joins**

Answer (score 3):

For discord.py 1.5.0, reference the [introduction of intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html).

Your bot will need the `members` intent - which happens to be a [priveleged intent](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#privileged-intents) - in order for the `on_member_join` event to be triggered properly.